# Critique of complex analysis proof

Tags: complex-analysis, proof-verification

I'm working on the following complex analysis problem and am wondering if someone could critique my proof:

> Suppose that $f$ is an analytic function on some domain $D$ and that
>   there exists a degree two polynomial $p$ such that $p \circ f$ is
>   real-valued. Show that $f \equiv C$ on $D$.

**My solution**: First we'll show that $f(z) \in \mathbb{R}$ for any $z \in D$ and then we'll deduce that $f$ must be constant.

Let $p(z) = a_0 + a_1z + a_2z^2$ and suppose that $f(z)$ is complex for some $z$. Observe that $(p \circ f)(z) = a_0 + a_1f(z) + a_2f^2(z)$. If $f(z)$ is complex, then $a_1f(z)$ is also complex, contradicting the problem statement. Thus, $f$ is real-valued.

Now we show that $f \equiv C$ on $D$. Write $f$ in the form $f(x,y) = u(x,y) + iv(x,y)$. Since $f$ is real-valued, $v_x = v_y = 0$. Thus, to satisfy the Cauchy-Riemann equations, we must have $u_x = u_v = 0$. Thus, $f \equiv C$ on $D$.

Comment: What if $a_1$ happens to be the complex conjugate of $f(z_0)$ for some $z_0$, in which case the term $a_1 f(z)$ would be real.

Comment: The second part seems ok. How can elaborate on the first part? The part $a_2f^2(z)$ can also be complex and cancel out with the $a_1f(z)$ part to make everything real.

Comment: I know you asked for a critique of your proof (and I agree with the critiques raised thus far). But in terms of a different proof: why not start by showing that $p\circ f$ must be a constant? You've already done so, in fact ... what can you conclude about $f$ from that?

Comment: @msteve yes but that would not be true for all $z_0 \in D$, where $D$ is a connected set, right?